# Function that returns a list of words of length n

Tags: list, haskell

Hey I am new to Haskell and trying to figure out how I would return a list with words of length n

```
getWords :: Int -> [Word] -> [Word]
getWords n w = filter (\x -> length x == n) w
```

I figured out I can use this in Prelude
filter (\x -> length x == 5) ["Hello", "23"]

It would return ["Hello"], however when I try to do it in a function getWords it gives me an error

```
* Couldn't match type `t0 a0' with `Word'
      Expected type: [Word]
        Actual type: [t0 a0]
    * In the expression: filter (\ x -> length x == n) w
      In an equation for `getWords':
          getWords n w = filter (\ x -> length x == n) w
    |
163 | getWords n w = filter (\x -> length x == n) w
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Date.hs:163:45: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Word' with `t0 a0'
      Expected type: [t0 a0]
        Actual type: [Word]
    * In the second argument of `filter', namely `w'
      In the expression: filter (\ x -> length x == n) w
      In an equation for `getWords':
          getWords n w = filter (\ x -> length x == n) w
    |
163 | getWords n w = filter (\x -> length x == n) w
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What type do you expect that `"Hello"` has? What sort of data type is `Word`, according to the Haskell documentation?

Comment: Is `Word` just `String` or `[Char]` in this case?

Comment: `Word` is a numeric type, unless you have redefined it somehow. You want a list of strings, i.e. `getWords :: Int -> [String] -> [String]`

Comment: @RoadRunner It doesn't matter; `type String = [Char]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is using `Word` presumably from `Data.Word`.  This is a machine word, as in an unsigned integral value.  It is not a human word, as in letters from a string.  As stated in the comments by @chi, you should use a `[String]`:

```
getWords :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
getWords n w = filter (\x -> length x == n) w
```

Comment: I got it from the book https://books.google.com.au/books?id=B4RxBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=getWords+::+Int+-%3E+%5BWord%5D+-%3E+%5BWord%5D+haskell&source=bl&ots=y3NsDj8AMo&sig=Vo_Fw-ukd09cqRTvlMhwh-2_cVc&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjyfinibXbAhWJ2LwKHbOlBVgQ6AEITzAF#v=onepage&q=getWords&f=false

Comment: So far as I see that book doesn't even define `Word`, so I'm not sure what the author was wanting there.

Comment: Ah, well the error shows the asker didn't use that type alias.  If they had included that alias and used a modern GHC then we'd have seen `Ambiguous occurrence ‘Word’`.